# PHP exec ls issue

Tags: php, terminal, exec

I am currently debugging some code and I am getting an error of: `ls: invalid option -- '/'`.  However if I try the value for `$somePath` in terminal it gives me the result.  Why am I getting the error?

**PHP:**

```
exec('ls -A' . $somePath.' | grep .', $output);
```

**Terminal Path:**

`ls -A /home/userName/public_html/path/folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you meant:

```
exec('ls -A ' . $somePath . ' | grep .', $output);
// SPACE --^
```

When getopt parses options starting with '-' but not with '--', it treats each character as an another option. It thought you passed options: 'A', '/', 'h', 'o', ... It just does not accept '/' character.